# Are Custom Python Geometry Nodes Possible? 3.0.1

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, pynodes

Right now, I have a little template that makes it pretty easy to make custom shader and compositor nodes, but it does not work with geometry nodes. The error happens when I register the custom geometry node class with `bpy.utils.register_class` and the python error says `TypeError: expected Node, GeoNodeTest class "poll" attribute to be a static/class method, not a bpy_func` I'm not sure how to interpret this. Is it saying that the parameter for `bpy.utils.register_class` expects a "Node" ?

Here's the template that helps create a node:

```
# Helps create a node and set up its io 
class NodeHelper():
    def __path_resolve__(self, obj, path):
        if "." in path:
            extrapath, path= path.rsplit(".", 1)
            obj = obj.path_resolve(extrapath)
        return obj, path
            
    def value_set(self, obj, path, val):
        obj, path=self.__path_resolve__(obj, path)
        setattr(obj, path, val)                

    def addNodes(self, nodes):
        for nodeitem in nodes:
            node=self.node_tree.nodes.new(nodeitem[0])
            for attr in nodeitem[1]:
                self.value_set(node, attr, nodeitem[1][attr])

    def addLinks(self, links):
        for link in links:
            if isinstance(link[0], str):
                if link[0].startswith('inputs'):
                    socketFrom=self.node_tree.path_resolve('nodes["Group Input"].outputs' + link[0][link[0].rindex('['):])
                else:
                    socketFrom=self.node_tree.path_resolve(link[0])
            else:
                socketFrom=link[0]
            if isinstance(link[1], str):
                if link[1].startswith('outputs'):
                    socketTo=self.node_tree.path_resolve('nodes["Group Output"].inputs' + link[1][link[1].rindex('['):])
                else:
                    socketTo=self.node_tree.path_resolve(link[1])
            else:
                socketTo=link[1]
            self.node_tree.links.new(socketFrom, socketTo)

    def addInputs(self, inputs):
        for inputitem in inputs:
            name = inputitem[1].pop('name')
            socketInterface=self.node_tree.inputs.new(inputitem[0], name)
            socket=self.path_resolve(socketInterface.path_from_id())
            for attr in inputitem[1]:
                if attr in ['default_value', 'hide', 'hide_value', 'enabled']:
                    self.value_set(socket, attr, inputitem[1][attr])
                else:
                    self.value_set(socketInterface, attr, inputitem[1][attr])
            
    def addOutputs(self, outputs):
        for outputitem in outputs:
            name = outputitem[1].pop('name')
            socketInterface=self.node_tree.outputs.new(outputitem[0], name)
            socket=self.path_resolve(socketInterface.path_from_id())
            for attr in outputitem[1]:
                if attr in ['default_value', 'hide', 'hide_value', 'enabled']:
                    self.value_set(socket, attr, outputitem[1][attr])
                else:
                    self.value_set(socketInterface, attr, outputitem[1][attr])
```

And here's me using it to make a simple shader node and attempt to do the same thing with a geometry node:

```
import bpy
# Basic node that makes a color from 3 floats and multiplies the result with some value
class TestShaderNode(bpy.types.ShaderNodeCustomGroup, NodeHelper):

    bl_name='TestShaderNode'
    bl_label='Make Color'
    bl_description = "Testing node with shared nodetree"

    def _set_node_tree(self):
        nt_name= '.' + self.bl_name + '_nodetree'
        if bpy.data.node_groups.find(nt_name)>-1:
            self.node_tree=bpy.data.node_groups[nt_name]
        else:    
            self.node_tree=bpy.data.node_groups.new(nt_name, 'ShaderNodeTree')
            
            # Add the nodes to be used in this node
            self.addNodes([
            ('NodeGroupInput', {'name':'Group Input'}), 
            ('NodeGroupOutput', {'name':'Group Output'}), 
            ('ShaderNodeMixRGB', {'name':'MultRGB', 'blend_type':'MULTIPLY'}),
            ('ShaderNodeCombineXYZ', {'name':'CombineXYZ'})
            ])
             
            # Add node inputs
            self.addInputs([('NodeSocketFloat', {'name':'Red', 'default_value':0.0, 'min_value':0.0, 'max_value':1.0}),])
            self.addInputs([('NodeSocketFloat', {'name':'Green', 'default_value':0.0, 'min_value':0.0, 'max_value':1.0}),])
            self.addInputs([('NodeSocketFloat', {'name':'Blue', 'default_value':0.0, 'min_value':0.0, 'max_value':1.0}),])
            self.addInputs([('NodeSocketFloat', {'name':'Strength', 'default_value':1.0, 'min_value':0.0, 'max_value':100.0}),])
            
            # Add node Outputs
            self.addOutputs([('NodeSocketColor', {'name':'Color out'})])
          
            
            # link inputs and outputs
            self.addLinks([('inputs[0]', 'nodes["CombineXYZ"].inputs[0]')]) # Red input to CombineXYZ input 0
            self.addLinks([('inputs[1]', 'nodes["CombineXYZ"].inputs[1]')]) # Green input to CombineXYZ input 1
            self.addLinks([('inputs[2]', 'nodes["CombineXYZ"].inputs[2]')]) # Blue input to CombineXYZ input 2
            self.addLinks([('nodes["CombineXYZ"].outputs[0]', 'nodes["MultRGB"].inputs[1]')]) # CombineXYZ output (vector) to MixRGB(multiply) input 1
            self.addLinks([('inputs[3]', 'nodes["MultRGB"].inputs[2]')]) # Strength input to MixRGB(multiply) input 2
            
            self.addLinks([('nodes["MultRGB"].outputs[0]', 'outputs[0]')]) # MixRGB output to our node's output
            
                       
    
    def init(self, context):
        self._set_node_tree()
        
    def copy(self, node):
        if not node.node_tree:
            self._new_node_tree()    
        
    def free(self):
        nt = self.node_tree
        if (nt.users <= 1):
            bpy.data.node_groups.remove(nt, do_unlink=True)






# Test geometry node
class GeoNodeTest(bpy.types.GeometryNodeCustomGroup, NodeHelper):

    bl_name='GeoNodeTest'
    bl_label='New Geometry node!'
    bl_description = "Testing node with shared nodetree"

    def _set_node_tree(self):
        nt_name= '.' + self.bl_name + '_nodetree'
        if bpy.data.node_groups.find(nt_name)>-1:
            self.node_tree=bpy.data.node_groups[nt_name]
        else:    
            self.node_tree=bpy.data.node_groups.new(nt_name, 'GeometryNodeTree')
            self.addNodes([('NodeGroupInput', {'name':'Group Input'}), ('NodeGroupOutput', {'name':'Group Output'})])
            
            self.addInputs([('NodeSocketFloat', {'name':'Value In', 'default_value':0.500}),])
            
            self.addOutputs([('NodeSocketFloat', {'name':'Value Out'})])
            
            self.addLinks([('inputs[0]', 'outputs[0]')])
                 
    
    def init(self, context):
        self._set_node_tree()
        
    def copy(self, node):
        if not node.node_tree:
            self._new_node_tree()    
        
    def free(self):
        nt = self.node_tree
        if (nt.users <= 1):
            bpy.data.node_groups.remove(nt, do_unlink=True)




     




from nodeitems_utils import NodeItem, register_node_categories, unregister_node_categories
from nodeitems_builtins import ShaderNodeCategory, GeometryNodeCategory


# Register the node classes
def register():

    # Register Shader nodes
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestShaderNode)
    
    
    # Register Geometry nodes
    #bpy.utils.register_class(GeoNodeTest)


    # Shader nodes
    shcat = [ShaderNodeCategory("SH_TESTING_NODES", "Testing Nodes Shader", items=[NodeItem("TestShaderNode")]),]
    
    # Geometry nodes
    geocat = [GeometryNodeCategory("GEO_TESTING_NODES", "Testing Nodes Geometry", items=[NodeItem("GeoNodeTest")]),]


    # Shader nodes
    register_node_categories("SH_TESTING_NODES", shcat)
    
    # Geometry nodes
    #register_node_categories("GEO_TESTING_NODES", geocat)


def unregister():
    unregister_node_categories("SH_TESTING_NODES")
    unregister_node_categories("GEO_TESTING_NODES")

    # Shader nodes
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestShaderNode)
    
    
    # Geometry nodes
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GeoNodeTest)

try :
    unregister()
except:
    pass
register()
```

Honestly, I don't really understand the purpose of making nodes this way. It seems you can do the exact same thing with node groups in blender. There must be more to the process of custom nodes that I'm missing. I was hoping to be able to do all the math and stuff in code but it looks like you have to use the existing math node? Is there more than one way to do this?

I've been looking around for general answers about scripting custom nodes and there just isn't much out there currently so any good resources would be appreciated (blender docs helped but not as much as I'd hoped.) Also, what exactly are Pynodes? Is that what I'm creating with the script?

Thank you in advance :)